# How I can write code in button's event of a form, from another form in a same name space?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, savechanges

I write code which get my data source data from a gridview in this form. But I can't find a way to change my data and save my context. Because my savebtn is on another form.

Here is my code:

```
namespace FactorEntity
{
    public partial class CustomerResearchForm : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
    {
        FactorEntities contex;
        public CustomerResearchForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CustomerResearchForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void CResearchGrid_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            
            
            CustomerUpdateAndDelete CustomerUpdateAndDelete = new CustomerUpdateAndDelete();
            contex = new FactorEntities();

            {       var sendergrid=(DataGridView)sender;

            int customercode = Convert.ToInt32(sendergrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value);
                    var customer = from _customer in contex.tblCustomers where
                                       _customer.CustomerCode==customercode select _customer;
                  
                    CustomerUpdateAndDelete.tblCustomerBindingSource.DataSource = customer.ToList();
                    CustomerUpdateAndDelete.Show();
                    
                    if (CustomerUpdateAndDelete.tblCustomerBindingNavigatorSaveItem.CheckOnClick == true)
                    {
                        contex.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    
                    
            }
        }

        
        
    }
}
```

And this is my  CustomerUpdateAndDelete form which tblCustomerBindingNavigatorSaveItem is here

```
namespace FactorEntity
{
    public partial class CustomerUpdateAndDelete :  MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
    {
        
        public CustomerUpdateAndDelete()
        {
        
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        
        private void CustomerUpdateAndDelete_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            
            
        }

        private void tblCustomerBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So your data is in one form and the save button is in a completely different form? That doesn't sound like such a good idea.

Comment: @sty what is your recommend ?